# listing matrices with some special constraint

Tags: matrix

Let we have

list = {{4, 4, 4, 4}, {-4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, -4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, -4, 4}, {4,4, 4, -4}, {-4, -4, 4, 4}, {-4, -4, -4, 4}, {-4, -4, -4, -4}}

I would like to first obtain the list of all possible 4 x 4 matrices which are created considering every 4 tuples in the above list as columns of the matrix.

From this list, I would like to have the list of  matrices satisfying the following properties at the same time.

1. Determinant is non-zero
2. Every row must contain at least a "4"
3. The row which is obtained by the sum of  any two rows must contain at least an "8".
4. If a higher index row is substracted from a lower index row, then there must be an "8"

thanks

Comment: [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/Tuples.html) is your friend here! You should post your code, too, for us to help you with, after you take a look at the link I posted.

Comment: (2)every row must contain at least a "4", then just ignore the last list.

Comment: Do you think there is a typo at 7th entry? May you meant `{-4,-4,-4,4}`

Comment: yes it is a typo, needs to be {-4,-4,-4,4}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit2** We can use @SHuisman condition checker

```
  list = {{4, 4, 4, 4}, {-4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, -4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, -4, 4}, {4,
     4, 4, -4}, {-4, -4, 4, 4}, {-4, -4, -4, 4}, {-4, -4, -4, -4}};
mat = Transpose /@ Permutations[list, {4}];
result = Select[mat, 
   Det@# != 0 && AllTrue[#, MemberQ[4]] && 
     AllTrue[Plus @@@ Subsets[#, {2}], MemberQ[8]] && 
     AllTrue[Subtract @@@ Subsets[#, {2}], MemberQ[8]] &];
Length@result
```

> 96

**Edit:**

```
list = {{4, 4, 4, 4}, {-4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, -4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, -4, 4}, {4,
      4, 4, -4}, {-4, -4, 4, 4}, {-4, -4, -4, 
     4}, {-4, -4, -4, -4}} /. {4 -> 1, -4 -> -1};
det = Select[mat, Det@# != 0 &];
cond2 = Map[MemberQ[#, 1] &, det, {2}];
det = Extract[det, Position[cond2, Table[True, 4]]];
cond3 = Map[MemberQ[#, 2] &, 
   Apply[#1 + #2 &, Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ det, {2}], {2}];
det = Extract[det, Position[cond3, Table[True, 6]]];
cond4 = Map[MemberQ[#, 2] &, 
   Apply[#1 - #2 &, Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ det, {2}], {2}];
result2 = Extract[det, Position[cond4, Table[True, 6]]];
 Length@result
```

> 96

You have repeated element 5th and 7th: delete 7th and the last one we will have

```
list = {{4, 4, 4, 4}, {-4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, -4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, -4, 4}, {4,
     4, 4, -4}, {-4, -4, 4, 4}};
```

Since Det will be zero whenever there are two identical rows, better to use `Permutations`

```
list = {{4, 4, 4, 4}, {-4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, -4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, -4, 4}, {4,
     4, 4, -4}, {-4, -4, 4, 4}};
mat = Permutations[list, {4}];
mat2 = Select[mat, Det@# != 0 &];
Length@mat2
```

> 312

Condition 3 automatically apply:

```
condition3 = Thread[Total /@ Total /@ Permutations[list, {2}] >= 8]
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
>   True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
>   True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100175/discussion-on-answer-by-okkesdulgerci-listing-matrices-with-some-special-constra).

Answer (score 0):

```
rows = {{4, 4, 4, 4}, {-4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, -4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, -4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, -4}, {-4, -4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, -4}};

det = Select[Tuples[rows, 4], Det@# =!= 0 &];

result = Select[det, 
   MemberQ[MemberQ[#, 8] & /@ (Total /@ Tuples[#, 2]), True] &];

Length /@ {det, result}
```

> {528, 528}

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using the WFR function **SelectPermutations**:

```
list = {{4, 4, 4, 4}, {-4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, -4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, -4, 4}, {4,
     4, 4, -4}, {-4, -4, 4, 4}, {-4, -4, -4, 4}, {-4, -4, -4, -4}};
out = ResourceFunction["SelectPermutations"][list, {4}, 
   Det[#] =!= 0 && AllTrue[#, MemberQ[4]] && 
     AllTrue[Plus @@@ Subsets[#, {2}], MemberQ[8]] && 
     AllTrue[Subtract @@@ Subsets[#, {2}], MemberQ[8]] &];
Length[out]
```

returns:

```
122
```

Comment: I run the code, but the length appears as 3 and also the outputs  are not working.

Comment: I think you need version 12  and a cloud account (free).

Comment: I run the code with version 12.  There is something wrong, for example  first ouput matrix is :  {{4, 4, 4, 4}, {-4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, -4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, -4, 4}} which does not satisfy the 4th condition. for instance,  2nd row minus 1st row does not give  an 8, but  It gives a -8.